# Is booting from M.2 SSD faster than Hybrid drive?

Tags: boot, hybrid-storage, m.2

I have a HP All-in-one with Windows 10 home installed on the Hybrid Drive. I plan to attach a M.2 SSD drive (option is available on the motherboard) and install my OS on it.
Now, is it worth doing that? Will it improve the OS performance?
I use lot of Video editing softwares, and believe that running these softwares via SSD will make them run faster. Am i right?
Does the HP **Bulldozer** motherboard even allow to Boot from a M.2 SSD?

Answer (score 0):

**SSDs can read and write data faster, so tasks that are limited by disk speeds will benefit from this upgrade.**

Obviously file transfers will be faster on an SSD, but you will also notice that Windows and programs start faster and are more responsive.

What will *not* be affected is performance of programs that are limited by something different than disk speed. For example rendering videos most likely won't be noticeably faster, because it's probably limited by computational capacity of your CPU or GPU, not disk's throughput.

Motherboards that support M.2 SSDs are capable of booting from them.

Comment: To complicate things: windows aggressively caches/memory maps files, even large ones. I once wrote a very simple file read program to test network throughput. The first run was as expected (e.g. 700mbit etc), but every following run for the same file, even for 1GB files tested out  at (e.g. 20,000 mbit) because they were being read from memory. Video editing software is something that benefits from this, given enough free RAM

Comment: Thank you. Does reinstalling the OS makes sense or cloning it? I asked HP support and they said that its not recommended since there are chances of the HDD getting fried. is that true? What do you suggest?

Comment: @Shyam That one goes on my "stupid stuff support people say" list. Cloning HDD is just reading it, it's safe. What I would worry about is if Windows will detect that it's now running on a SSD and adjust its disk maintenance routines, I'm not sure how it will handle that. I'd probably go with a clean install if it's not too much of a hassle to install all software you use.